# SSRS add Total row with differences

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I want to add a total row in Reporting Services where the difference (in numbers and percent is available). Attached you'll se the current img in SSRS and the requested output in Excel as example.

**SSRS**

[image]

**Excel**

[image]

Comment: Can there be more than 2 rows. From 2013 To 2015?

Comment: I prefer to add a control to just have 2 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you are going to compare only two years you can use this approach.

To calculate change from one year to the next.

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!year.Value= Parameters!Yearfrom.Value,Fields!incurred_losses.Value,0)-
Sum(iif(Fields!year.Value= Parameters!Yearto.Value,Fields!incurred_losses.Value,0)
```

For change in percentage:

```
=(Sum(iif(Fields!year.Value= Parameters!Yearfrom.Value,Fields!incurred_losses.Value,0)-
Sum(iif(Fields!year.Value= Parameters!Yearto.Value,Fields!incurred_losses.Value))/
Sum(iif(Fields!year.Value= Parameters!Yearfrom.Value,Fields!incurred_losses.Value,0)
```

Use this expression for every column in your tablix.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Great!! that worked. I just added a minor change to prevent error  **[rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes]** =Sum(IIf(Fields!Year.Value=Parameters!EndDate.Value,CDbl(Fields!Incurred_Losses.Value),0))-Sum(IIf(Fields!Year.Value=Parameters!StartDate.Value,CDbl(Fields!Incurred_Losses.Value),0))

Comment: Oh nice, I forgot validation for division by zero. Fortunately you are cautious. just be sure you are using the right cell format.